Fuse:getattr where path includes wildcards
I noticed that paths may include wildcards when system is calling the fuse getattr.
What is the expected return for such call, as a wikdcard can be no match (ENOENT) or having exactly one match (rc 0), or muktiple matches?
The first two is obvious what to return, but if there are multiple matches?

Eg stat /myfuse/mydir/myfiles.*

As a filesystem, it's not your job to expand wildcards - that's a job for a shell.  Just treat the filename as an exact string - if you're passed foo*, it's only successful if there's a file called exactly foo*.
Often, being passed a * or ? in a pathname happens when a shell tries to expand a wildcard and there are no matches.  But a user could intentionally include them, quoting with any of the shell's available mechanisms.
